# Python: Append additional lines to list created with startswith()

Tags: python, loops, startswith

I have a text file in the format

```
AN   text
     text
TI   text
AU   text
     text
     text
CS   text
SO   text

AN   text
TI   text
AU   text
     text
CS   text
     text
SO   text
```

etc, where there are keywords of two capital letters, followed by additional text on one or more extra lines.

The number of lines after the keyword can vary, so I can't just get the next one or two for example, but the order of the keywords remains the same.

What I want to do is get all the text from a selection of these keywords (e.g. just `AN`, `AU` and `SO`). I started by using `readlines()` to parse the file and then with:

```
sorted_text = []
for line in file:
    if line.startswith('AN'):
        line = line.rstrip('\n')
        sorted_text.append(line)
```

After that it all goes wrong! I was aiming to then append the next line in the list to this one, unless it started with `TI`, but any elif/else loops I seem to try append too many extra lines.

Is this even a sensible way to go about solving this sort of problem or is there a better approach to start with?

Answer (score 0):

You can use a "currentKey" variable to keep track of the current keyword that you have seen:

```
currentKey = ''
sorted_text = []
keywords = set(['AN', 'AU', 'SO'])
for line in file:
    if line.startswith('AN'): 
        currentKey = 'AN'
    elif line.startswith('TI'): 
        currentKey = 'TI'
    elif line.startswith('AU'): 
        currentKey = 'AU'
    elif line.startswith('CS'): 
        currentKey = 'CS'
    elif line.startswith('SO'): 
        currentKey = 'SO'

    if currentKey in keywords:
        line = line.rstrip('\n')
        sorted_text.append(line)
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
from collections import defaultdict

d, k = defaultdict(), None

for line in open(r"C:\Temp\test.txt"):
    data = [s for s in line.split(" ") if s != ""]
    if len(data) > 1: k, t = data[0], data[1]
    else: t = data[0]
    d[k] = d.get(k, "") + t 

print d
```

if you want to get your texts into list, than change `d[k] = d.get(k, "") + t` to `d.setdefault(k, []).append(t)`

Comment: Your solution could be easily changed to allow space in texts - add `'maxsplit=1'` parameter to `'line.split(" ")'`.
And perhaps `lstrip()` should be called on `line` before splitting it.
And `d` could be ordinary dict, `defaultdict()` is not necessary :)

Answer (score 0):

Use regular expressions:

```
>>> import re
>>> exp=re.compile(r'^([A-Z]{2})(.+?)(?=(^[A-Z])|\Z)',re.S| re.VERBOSE | re.MULTILINE)
>>> for s in exp.finditer(ifile): print('|',s.group(1),'>',s.group(2))
... 
| AN >    text
     text

| TI >    text

| AU >    text
     text
     text

| CS >    text

| SO >    text


| AN >    text

| TI >    text

| AU >    text
     text

| CS >    text
     text

| SO >    text


>>> print(ifile)
AN   text
     text
TI   text
AU   text
     text
     text
CS   text
SO   text

AN   text
TI   text
AU   text
     text
CS   text
     text
SO   text
```

so you have 2-letter code in group(1), text after that in group(2).

Answer (score 0):

Your text looks like YAML file except of no colons (:)

if you can modify writer of this file(if any) like this syntax:

```
AN:
    text
    text
```

you may use YAML parser.